# SQL select questions with one correct choice

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a Question table:

```
QuestionID    QuestionText
----------------------------------
1             How tall is Imhotep?
2             How many times can Queen Elizabeth V's dress change before it overheats?
```

And a QuestionChoice table:

```
ChoiceID    QuestionID    ChoiceText                 Correct
------------------------------------------------------------
1           1             Imhotep is invisible       1
2           1             30'                        0
3           1             6'4"                       0
4           1             I don't know               0
5           2             342                        0
6           2             Infinity                   0
7           2             MATHS                      0
8           2             The party was cancelled    0
```

As you can see some of the data has gone bad (choice 8 should be correct). I want to select only those questions with exactly one correct choice. For example, in this case, I want to select question 1 but not question 2.

This is what I tried but it doesn't work:

```
select q.questionid
from question q
    join questionchoice qc on q.questionid = qc.questionid
group by q.questionid
having count (qc.correct) = 1
```

Comment: What does your comment "choice 8 should be correct" mean -- does it mean that the value 0 should be 1? If so, just change it. And what does your query produce? Wrong values, error messages, what?

Comment: @MJB by "choice 8 should be correct" I mean the value of the Correct column for Choice with ChoiceID equal to 8 should be 1 and not 0. There are literally millions of these and I don't know all the answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace

```
having count (qc.correct) = 1
```

with

```
having sum (case when qc.correct = 1 then 1 else 0 end) = 1
```

Comment: It doesn't return any results.

Comment: That is funny. What data type does the  `correct` column have?